# Down, Away or Ahead

Tags: word-usage, difference, adverbs

> I bet there's a rest stop a couple of miles **down**.
>
> I bet there's a rest stop a couple of miles **away**.
>
> I bet there's a rest stop a couple of miles **ahead**.

What sounds natural "down", "away" or "ahead"?

And if some asks "we're still not there yet." and the person replies:

> We're close. The map says that it's just a mile **away/down/ahead**.

Comment: Well, _ahead_ means in front, while _away_ could be 2 miles in any direction. We might say _down the road_, but we wouldn't use _down_ on its own in this context.

Comment: So @KateBunting what works better "away" or "ahead"? And in the second context, what works better "ahead" or "away"?

Comment: You could use either, or _further on_, in either sentence.

Comment: It could be an AmE vs BrE thing (and I doubt that too), but "it's ten miles down" with nothing afterwards doesn't seem natural English to me.  You need to add a word or two at the end to make it sound idiomatic. down the road, down there, down south, down the valley or something.

Answer (score 0):

To further confuse the issue, you could also say "down the road" or "up the road" or "up ahead." All of these expressions have exactly the same meaning.  It has nothing to do with the altitude or hills along the road.  No wonder English is nearly impossible to learn if you weren't born here!